# Quantum Computer - Rotation Bloch Sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-computer, bloch-sphere

please can anyone help?
What gate combination allows moving from the state between |0> and |1> states. In terms of bloch-sphere from the north pole to the south pole as an example. And how can we make sure that it's correct for different angles?

Answer (score 1):

The NOT gate (sometimes called the Pauli X gate) swaps $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states. This is equivalent to a classical [inverter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate)).

Not sure what you mean by “how can we be sure it is correct for different angles”. Like all quantum logic gates, NOT is linear, so it maps $\alpha |0\rangle +\beta |1\rangle$ to $\beta |0\rangle +\alpha |1\rangle$.

Comment: I mean how is it possible to run the test with different angles between 0-180° to make sure it is working in both ways. We can move from the |0> state to the |1> state and vice versa no matter what angle is used but not through the equator (~Hadamard state) but from the north pole to the South or the opposite.

Comment: Note that there is also a "universal not gate" (which maps every point on the bloch sphere to the opposite one, and which does not exist), which would be much more rightfully the quantum version of a classical inverter.